# Calling a property or method using an attribute name

Tags: c#, reflection, methods, properties, attributes

Let's say I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class CallByAttribute
{
    [CodeName("Foo")]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    [CodeName("Bar")]
    public string MyMethod(int someParameter)
    {
         return myDictionary[someParameter];
    }
}
```

How would I call these two properties or methods, using CodeName instead of the property or method name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Method 1:**

```
public static TOutput GetPropertyByCodeName<TOutput>(this object obj, string codeName)
{
    var property = obj.GetType()
                      .GetProperties()
                      .Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(CodeNameAttribute), false))
                      .Single(p => ((CodeNameAttribute)(p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CodeNameAttribute), false).First())).Name == codeName);

    return (TOutput)property.GetValue(obj, null);
}
```

Note: This will throw if no property exists with the specified `codeName` or if multiple properties share the same `codeName`.

Usage:

```
CallByAttribute obj= ...
string myProperty = obj.GetPropertyByCodeName<string>("Foo");
```

---

**Method 2:**

If you are on C# 4, you can write your own [`System.Dynamic.DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) that can route dynamic calls to the right member.

This will allow for cleaner syntax. For example, you should be able to accomplish something that allows:

```
CallByAttribute obj= ...
dynamic objectByCodeName = new ObjectByCodeName(obj);
objectByCodeName.Foo = "8";
objectByCodeName.Bar();
```

Comment: It looks like you need a companion `Attribute` class for `CodeName`; is that true, or can you just reflect over the properties to get the CodeName for each?

Comment: Robert: Presumably you already have a `CodeNameAttribute` class, otherwise you wouldn't be able to do `[CodeName("foo")]` because that actually causes an instantiation of a `CodeNameAttribute` object.

Comment: If you're going to be using these codenames a lot (thousands or millions of times), you'll want to cache the results of the property lookup as delegates that you can lookup in a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some fully working code including optional call arguments:

```
    private static string Call(object callByAttribute, string name, object[] args)
    {
        PropertyInfo prop = callByAttribute.GetType().GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(CodeNameAttribute), false))
             .SingleOrDefault(p => ((CodeNameAttribute)(p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CodeNameAttribute), false)).First()).Name == name);
        if (prop != null)
            return (string)callByAttribute.GetType().InvokeMember(prop.Name, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, callByAttribute, null);


        MethodInfo method = callByAttribute.GetType().GetMethods()
            .Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(CodeNameAttribute), false))
             .SingleOrDefault(p => ((CodeNameAttribute)(p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CodeNameAttribute), false)).First()).Name == name);
        if (method != null)
            return (string)callByAttribute.GetType().InvokeMember(method.Name,  BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, callByAttribute, args);

        throw new Exception("method/getter not found");
    }
    private static string Call(object callByAttribute, string name)
    {
        return Call(callByAttribute, name, null);
    }
```

This can be used in a complete program like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
public class CallByAttribute
{
    [CodeName("Foo")]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    [CodeName("Bar")]
    public string MyMethod(int someParameter)
    {
        return "blah" + someParameter;
    }
}

public class CodeNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly string name;

    public CodeNameAttribute(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CallByAttribute callByAttribute = new CallByAttribute();
        callByAttribute.MyProperty = "hi";

        Console.WriteLine(Call(callByAttribute, "Bar", new object[] {1}));
        Console.WriteLine(Call(callByAttribute, "Foo"));

    }
    private static string Call(object callByAttribute, string name)
    {
        return Call(callByAttribute, name, null);
    }


    private static string Call(object callByAttribute, string name, object[] args)
    {
        PropertyInfo prop = callByAttribute.GetType().GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(CodeNameAttribute), false))
             .SingleOrDefault(p => ((CodeNameAttribute)(p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CodeNameAttribute), false)).First()).Name == name);
        if (prop != null)
            return (string)callByAttribute.GetType().InvokeMember(prop.Name, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, callByAttribute, null);

        MethodInfo method = callByAttribute.GetType().GetMethods()
            .Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(CodeNameAttribute), false))
             .SingleOrDefault(p => ((CodeNameAttribute)(p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CodeNameAttribute), false)).First()).Name == name);
        if (method != null)
            return (string)callByAttribute.GetType().InvokeMember(method.Name,  BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, callByAttribute, args);

        throw new Exception("method/getter not found");
    }
}
}
```